# Low Water Pressure after sprinkler work

Tags: sprinkler-system

I just recently had to do some work on my main sprinkler shut off. All went well but when I turned my house water back on (had it off from the street and in the house) our pressure is low. It's a bit down everywhere but it's very noticeable on our fridge dispenser. I tried disconnecting the line and letting it drain in case there was air in the line. Any ideas?

Comment: Disconnecting and draining the line seems to me like it would put air in the line.

Comment: There's a leak in the sprinter piping, mst likely before the valves, allowing a lot of water to escape.    Did they put a cut off valve to stop water to the sprinkler system?   If so shut it off.

Comment: I was worried air had gotten into the line and that it was trapped. There is a cut off valve that's what I was working on. There are no leaks at that point but that is a good thing to test.

Comment: shut off all taps ... if you have a water meter, then check if it is showing water flow .... if you do not have a meter, shut off the main supply valve, wait 30 seconds or so, then turn back on a very small amount and listen for the sound of running water. (hissing sound)  .... leave the main valve turned on just a small amount ... if the sound of running water does not stop, then you have a leak

Comment: If there us no leak, did you remove to faucet aerators before you ran after after shutting the water off and then turning water back on?     Any trapped air will be removed on first turning faucets back on

Comment: I suspect the answer is you’ve knocked loose scale and now need to clean the faucet aerators.

Comment: All faucets/showers or only a few ? Both Hot and Cold Water ?

Comment: It seems the main supply from the street needed a few more turns. Water pressure seems normal now. Thanks guys!

Comment: Okay i'm back problem is weirder. Pressure is fine for a bit then suddenly it drops again with no change in use i.e i could be filling a glass at the fridge when no other water is in use and it suddenly drops pressure. Help! haha